# Javascript: New image not appearing in Firefox and IE

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I am creating an image on a button press. The image gets created when I run it in Chrome but I can not get anything to show up in Firefox or IE. I have seen this question asked other places online but have not had any luck getting this to work for me.

Button HTML:

```
<input type="radio" class="button" name="button" onclick="createImageRoof();" id="button1"/>
```

JS:

```
function createImageRoof()
{
    alert("In Function")
    var floatingImage1= document.getElementById('floatingImage1');
    var i1 = document.createElement("img");
    i1.src = "Images\\tnR1.png";
    i1.type = "image";
    floatingImage1.appendChild(i1);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the file path directory separators to forward slashes (/) worked for me.

So: `i1.src = "Images/tnR1.png";`